# How to bring an application to the front with picoe/Eto on Mac OSX?

Tags: eto

I want to minimize the main window of a C#/Eto app and switch to another program. But when a timer in the Eto app fires it opens a new window, which I want to see. It should be displayed on top of all other windows currently open. The focus may switch to that window, but it's ok if not.

Using `BringToFront()` of the `Form` class does not work.

What else could I do?

Comment: did you get it working? If so please mark my answer as correct so people in the future can fix this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the way Apple made OS X, you are unable to make a window go to the top with programming. On Windows it is different.

Good luck!